# Can I benchmark a multithreaded code using quick-bench.com?

Tags: c++, multithreading, benchmarking

[quick-bench.com](https://www.quick-bench.com/) is a nice tool to compare the performance of two snippets of code, but what if those snippets are multithreaded, does quick-bench restrict the number of cores you can use and in that case how many are used?

The code I was trying to benchmark: https://www.quick-bench.com/q/sRHEEGpXFE-cFQYeRRL8QiVcL-M

Comment: if you do the same work distributed to 2 threads then the CPU time should be the same, and thats what one can see in your benchmark

Comment: wait a sec. aren't the two benchmarks identical?

Comment: No in one of the functions I'm unlocking before notifying other threads `second_2` and in the other function `second` the lock is unlocked after being out of scope.

Comment: nevertheless CPU time should be same, no?

Comment: Yes, that's what I believe, but some behaviors in a multithreaded code cannot appear unless we have threads running in multiple cores, or am I wrong?

Comment: how many cores are used is typically the OS buisness. You control threads not cores

Comment: I agree with that, but I would like to know how many cores are used because you can't state that a given multithreaded code is good and scales if you don't check with a different number of cores and loads.